# C#: grabbing values from a DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a form that contains a datagridview. Basically this form is used to query clients from a database. After the user does the search, the results are displayed on the DGV. I want the user to be able to click on the client that they want and be able to view their information on another form. When new clients are added to the DB, it will be given a unique ID, so I will be using that when actually opening the form with the information. But how would I be able to retrieve that ID from the DGV by clicking on the row?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry everyone I forgot to mention one thing. The clients are searched by client name at first. The user will type a name in a textbox and click the search button. The database is then queried by the name. The retrieved clients are then listed in the DGV. From there, the user selects the client that they are looking for and the form with their info pops up.
sorry for the confusion

Comment: Then... have you got an ID Column (visible or hidden) in your datagridview?

Answer (score 0):

Set the Unique-ID as a tagged object in your ItemCollection.

Try this:

```
DataGridView.Items[n].Tag = (object)YOUR_UNIQUE_ID
```

(of course the same command if you want your id)

Answer (score 0):

Using `CType`, you get the row's Primary key value from the DataGridView. The following is one example:

```
Name = CType(dgview.FindControl("lblname"),Label).Text
```

After retrieving the value like the above, you write a query to search with that key. After retrieving the ID value from the database, bind the DataGridView again to show the searched result.

Comment: Note that `CType` is only available in VB.NET (but even there, you should prefer `DirectCast`). The question is about C#, which would require a different style of cast.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the grid, setting the SelectionMode property to FullRowSelect.

I suppose that you load the data into the datagridview using something like

```
GrdClients.DataSource = ListsOfClients
```

So, you will need to handle the CellMouseDoubleClick event of the grid. As you previous configure the SelectionMode property to FullRowSelect, you can now extract the selected client

```
Client ClientElement = GrdRequests.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem
ShowClientForm(ClientElement.Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to make sure that DGV contains the ID column (you may hide it by setting Visible property to false)
Then, you have to handle DGV.CellClick event:
(sorry for VB, copy paste from actual code)

`If e.RowIndex < 0 Then Exit Sub

Dim id as integer = dgv.Item(0, e.RowIndex).Value`

where 0 is the index of column containing your Client ID.

Comment: dvg.item has an overload that uses the column name instead of the index. Try to use the column name when possible.